# Passing returned variable to php variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script that performs a lookup the name of a company and returns the image associated with the company. This works fine but I would like to pass the image name to a PHP variable, is this possible? The jQuery code I use to lookup the company is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#CompanyImage').load('check_image.php').show();

    $('#ClientName').keyup(function() {
        $.post('check_image.php', { client: NewBooking.ClientName.value }, function(output) {
            //$('#CompanyImage').html(result).show();
            $("#CompanyImage").html("<img src=\"../../../conf/conf_images/boards/" + output + "\">");
        });
    });
});
```

If I have a PHP variable named `CompanyImage` how can I copy the returned image name to the variable? Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You're getting the image name from PHP, so presumably it's already a PHP variable. Please clarify your question a bit.

Comment: `check_image.php` returns only the image name or white file extension? Check what you got with `console.log(output);` in your $.post callback.

Comment: @Mike, Hi, the iamge name is returned in "$("#CompanyImage").html("<img src=\"../../../conf/conf_images/boards/" + output + "\">");"  and I display the image in a DIV, but how can I use the name of the iamge in another PHP variable named $CompamyImage. Many thanks for you time.

Comment: @DCJones `output` comes from PHP, so it's already a PHP variable. Your question still is not clear.

Comment: @ Mike, if output hold the name of the image how can I use "output" as a variable. Like echo $output; Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @DCJones you mean using `output` outside of ajax-callback? Thats no good idear. Use Events for this part. Btw: `output` is variable with which you can work inside ajax-callback. What is your goal?

Comment: @pleinx Hi, I need to pass the name the image to a MySQL insert query. So in simple terms, a user types in the name of a company, as they do so the jquery call looks for the name of the company and returns the image. The name of the image is then used within the insert query. I know that this may sound odd but the project I am working requires this to be done. Many thanks for looking at my issue.

Comment: Okay just for me that i understand you right: `check_image.php` delivers the current image of that was user is typing in? And that result you want to send to PHP and insert into your mySQL DB?

Comment: Hi pleinx, that exactly right, User types in a name: check_image.php looks up the image and displays it on screen. User completes the Form and submits it, and the name of the image is used in the MySQL insert.

Comment: Hi all, I still can't get the result from my jQuery call in to a PHP variabe which I can use else where. Can anyone help please.